# i just can't seem to make json work. full stop. i pretty much copied http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ with no luck

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

[image]

---

```
        $("#thumbnails .thumb").find(".viewsCount").each(function(){
        var PostID = $(this).html();
        $.getJSON("http://tom.is-a-geek.org/tumblr/counters/thomee/go.php?c=yeeeboiii&i=" + PostID + "&justCount=y&format=json&jsoncallback=?",function(data){
             $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                //$(this).html(item.views); 
                alert(item.views);
                alert("sigh");
            });         
        });
    });
```

---

```
({
    "items": [
     {
        "views": "20"
     }
    ]
})
```

---

live @ http://thomee.tumblr.com

any assistance would be appreciated. :-(

Comment: FWIW, that JSON is invalid. See my CW answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do a cross-site `getJSON` due to security reasons. So either use local (I mean local as in "same domain") url in `getJSON` or try using a JSONP hack/workaround: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/

Comment: oh my goddddd
I read about json and jsonp on jquery.com and couldn't determine the differences =.=

it's sad I'm still making the same error... I was up at 4 this morning... took me 2 hours to realise I was trying to XSS... make the same error all the time *sigh*

thanks guys

Comment: `$.jsonp({ url: "http://tom.is-a-geek.org/tumblr/counters/thomee/go.php?c=yeeeboiii&i=" + PostID + "&justCount=y&format=json&callback=?" }, function(data){ alert("sigh"); });`

has no effect
i don't get the "sigh" alert either :/

Answer (score 2):

As [František says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727174/i-just-cant-seem-to-make-json-work-full-stop-i-pretty-much-copied-http-api-j/5727214#5727214), cross-site ajax (`getJSON` is ajax under-the-covers) is restricted by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You have lots of options, though:

- As František says, you can use [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) if the server in question supports it.
- If the target server supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and the browser your visitor is using supports it (recent versions), it will work (except that the versions of IE that support CORS — 8 and 9 — requires special handling rather than having it Just Work as it does in Firefox and Chrome).
- You can use [YQL as a proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax).

(This is a CW because it's really just a big adjunct to František's answer. Didn't feel comfortable adding all of this to that answer, although in theory of course that's what StackOverflow is all about, collaboratively answering questions.)

---

Separately, FYI, the JSON you quoted:

```
({
    "items": [
     {
        "views": "20"
     }
    ]
})
```

...is invalid, [JSON](http://json.org/) has no parenthesis operator. That should be:

```
{
    "items": [
     {
        "views": "20"
     }
    ]
}
```

The reason you sometimes see parentheses near JSON text is that when evaluating JSON, sometimes people will use the JavaScript parser to parse JSON (since JSON is a subset of JavaScript's object literal notation):

```
var result = eval("(" + jsonString + ")");
```

They put the parentheses in to ensure that the contents of the `jsonString` are evaluated by the parser where an *expression* is expected. But the parentheses are not part of the JSON and a proper JSON parser will fail if you use the JSON you quoted. (Re this `eval` technique: **Only** use it if you know the source of the JSON is trustworthy [your own server, etc.]; otherwise, best to use an actual JSON parser to defend against script injection attacks, the parentheses are not remotely a projection against those. You can find three JSON parsers — one that relies on `eval` but does some checks first, and two that don't use `eval` at all — on [the github page of Douglas Crockford](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/), inventor of JSON.)

Comment: changes made... but now I have a new issue hehe: `invalid label "item http://tom.is-a-geek.org/tumblr/counters/thomee/go.php?c=yeeeboiii&i=4604215109&justCount=y&format=json&callback=_jqjsp&_1303291632850=
Line 2`